# Enabling class methods to be called in a specific way

Tags: c#, attributes

What I would like to be able to do is to add an attribute to specific methods of a class so that those methods so decorated could have the statements in their body be called in a manner that I liked.

For example, consider this scenario in C#:

```
public class A
    {
    public A() {}

    [CallTwice()]
    public void Func1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Calling Func1().");
    }

    public void Func2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Calling Func2().");
    }
}
```

I would like a scenario where if I did this:

```
public static void Main()
{
    A a = new A();
    a.Func1();
    a.Func2();
}
```

I would get this output:

```
Calling A.Func1().
Calling A.Func1().
Calling A.Func2().
```

i.e. my decoration of Func1 makes it to be called twice.

What I would like to know is how I could write code to take advantage of the specific decoration I have given to Func1 so that I would know to call its body statements twice. Is this possible in C#?

Comment: I'm curious what you're trying to achieve by doing this? On the surface, it just makes the code more difficult to follow. What's the goal?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to declaratively separate the implementation of a method from how the method is called. This way, if I need to change how the method is called, I only need to change the implementation attribute that the method is decorated with, rather than changing the method itself.

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply make Func1 private or protected, and make different method, that calls Func1 twice?

```
public class A
{
public A() {}

public void Func1()
{
    Func1Core();
    Func1Core();
}

private void Func1Core()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Calling Func1().");
}

public void Func2()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Calling Func2().");
}
}
```

Comment: you could even specify the parameter for Func1 telling it how many times to run it...

Answer (score 0):

You can make Func1 to recursively call itself by decrementing a count variable for each call.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps in this case but [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) allows you to decorate methods with attributes for special purpose.

http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/documentation

Comment: Yes, I had thought of aspect oriented programming as a solution to the problem. But it looks like what you propose only allows me to add additional functionality to the method, rather than calling it multiple times.